# Threads start while screen still locked, want to prevent

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have a layout that has some control buttons and a custom view (`MainView`) in the bottom of the `HorizontalLayout`.  The `MainView` starts a `ControllerThread` that in turn starts other threads.  My goal is to not start the `ControllerThread` until the screen has been unlocked and the `HorizontalLayout` is definitely visible to the user.

(henceforth `ControllerThread` is `_ctrlr`)

I first naively put the `_ctrlr.start()` in the `MainView`'s constructor.  Then I placed it in `onFinishInflation()`, but this is called before the screen is unlocked.  My last attempt was to place it in `onWindowVisibilityChanged()` and start the controller if `visibility` is set to `VISIBLE`, but even this is called prior to the screen being unlocked.  I'm assuming that those functions are called prior to the screen being unlocked, since the `_ctrlr` is confirmed to be running.

Is there a method available in `View`'s to check if the screen is locked/unlocked?  Or do I have to maybe use the `KeyguardManager`?

Comment: IMO due of MVC you should put the ControllerThread inside the activity that inflates tour MainView. Then you can use the onResume/onPause callbacks to start/stop your thread

Comment: When you said the screen is locked, do you mean the user is on lock screen or your view is not visible to the user?

Comment: the user is on the lock screen

Answer (score 0):

Per blackbelt's suggestion, I moved the call to start the thread to the controller by creating a public class in the `MainView` that will start the controller when it's called.  In OnResume of the `MainActivity` I call:

```
((MainView) findViewById(R.id.mainView)).startController();
```

The `ControllerThread` will now not start until the app is actually pulled up in the emulator after you unlock the screen.